# where is the sys module in python source code?

Tags: python, module

I have found most python modules in python source directory, under Python/Lib or Python/Modules ,but where is the sys (import sys) module ? I didn't find it .

Comment: If you're using *nix, this command pattern is quite useful to find files with a portion of a string (such as "sys") in them: `find ./* | grep -i sys`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### The Answer

I find it here: `./Python/sysmodule.c`

If you're on Linux or Mac OS X, and in doubt, just try `find . -name 'sysmodule.c'` in the Python directory.

### Other Stuff

The way I found it was by searching for the string `"platform"` throughout the Python directory (using TextMate), as I've used e.g. `sys.platform` before from the `sys` module... something similar can be done with `grep` and `xargs`.

Another suggestion could be : `for i in ./**/*.c ; do grep -H platform $i ; done`

This will loop through all `*.c` files present in anywhere up the file tree you're currently located at, and search the file for `"platform"`. The `-H` flag will ensure we get a filename path so we can trace the matches back to the files they are found in.

Comment: Cool. Now, where are the pydocs source for this module, which I suppose is what I was really looking for.

Comment: @MichaelScheper : are these the docs, perhaps? 

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html

Answer (score 7):

```
import sys
help(sys)
```

Then you will see something like the following:

```
Help on built-in module sys:

NAME
    sys

FILE
    (built-in)
```

In my working environment, **sys** is built into python itself.

Comment: This is useful because it works for other modules, like `unittest` that I was looking for today.

Answer (score 2):

It's in `Python/Python/sysmodule.c`.

Comment: couldn't find it in Python 3.11 version