# Retrieve all builtin functions

Tags: python, function, built-in

I intent to retrieve a list of default Built-in Functions specified in [2. Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html)

How to list them all?

Just as list all the keywords as:

```
python
import keyword
keyword.kwlist
```

is it possible to list all the 68 functions?

---

This is my first question on SO, please note that it definitely not duplicate to the existing stuff on stackoverflow or even the world.

My question asked about the 68 builtin functions listed by docs which are absolutely different from `dir(__builtins__)`:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will show all builtins:

```
>>> dir(__builtins__)
['ArithmeticError', 'AssertionError', ...,  'type', 'vars', 'zip']
```

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: Unfortunately I don't know *quite* every Python question on this site yet.

Comment: If it's not a duplicate you may want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370206/how-to-get-a-list-of-built-in-modules-in-python).

Comment: dir(__builtins__) list all the 151 builtin libraries nor to show the 68 functions. @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: the question did not duplicate, see my answer @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: The exact same answer was present in the question I marked here. Duplicate answers are fine.

Comment: `dir(__builtins__)' lists all the 151 libraries nor the 68 functions. @TomWojcik

Comment: Could you please deactivate you downvote, my question is not duplicate @coldspeed

Comment: Could you please deactivate you downvote, my question is not duplicate @TomWojcik

Comment: @JawSaw I'm not the one who downvoted your question. Asking people to revoke their downvote won't work here, especially if you ask random people. Don't do that. It's just how it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
class BuiltinFunctions_42:
    def __init__(self):
        self.in = ['input']
        self.file = ['open']
        self.number =  ['hex', 'oct', 'abs', 'round', 'divmod', 'pow', 'sum']
        self.string =  ['format', 'ord', 'chr', 'ascii', 'bin']
        self.obj = ['id']
        self.sequence = ['hash', 'len', 'max', 'min']
        self.iterator = ['all', 'any','iter', 'next']
        self.function = ['callable']
        self.code =  ['eval', 'exec', 'compile']
        self.klass = ['__build_class__', 'issubclass']
        self.instance = ['repr','isinstance', 'hasattr',  'getattr', 'setattr', 'delattr']
        self.module = ['__import__']

        self.dubug = {'introspection':{'locals', 'globals'}}
        self.out = ['print', 'dir', 'vars']
```